# Controller not invoked in spring-mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm a beginner to spring-mvc. I was trying to create a login page using spring-mvc. But my controller is not invoked on submit button. I get the 404 error.

**login.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorator="layout/default">
    <head lang="en">
        <title>User Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>        
        <form method="POST" action="/SpringApplication/postLogin" >
            <table>
                <tr><td>User Name: </td><td><input name="userName" type="textbox"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Password: </td><td><input name="password" type="password"></td></tr>
                <tr><td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
            </table>
            <div style="color:red">${error}</div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**LoginController.java**

```
package core.controllers;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


@Controller
public class LoginController {

    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/SpringApplication/postLogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postSearch(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        if (userName.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
            model.addAttribute("error", "Please enter some value!");
            return "redirect:/";
        }
        model.addAttribute("msg", "success");
        return "resultPage";
    }
}
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="login.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->
    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="login" />

</beans>
```

**Project Structure**

[image]

Comment: share viewresolver configuration and jsp folder structure

Comment: @DarkKnight, added the requested file..

Answer (score 0):

Your button's action is

```
action="/SpringApplication/postSearch"
```

while your controller maps

```
value = "/SpringApplication/postLogin"
```

Try to change your controller's mapping to

```
value = "/SpringApplication/postSearch"
```

edit: you seem to have fixed above issue. But your controller wants to return a jsp file called `"resultPage"` which is nowhere to be found in your jsp folder.

Comment: That is a mistake @CheshireCat .. I corrected it but it still doesn't work

Comment: When I debug this application, the cursor never steps into the controller part.. so I didn't create the `resultPage`(didn't bother)

Comment: Is this your only controller, or do you have some that are already working?

Comment: Yes.. This is my only controller

Comment: Then maybe there are some problems with your spring/bean configurations. It might be an idea to download a working tutorial and then change it, s.t. it meets your requirements. Thats how I got my first Spring MVC project running.

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong action property on your `form` .

Controller is waiting for a `"/SpringApplication/postLogin"`  request, and the form is submitting to  `"/SpringApplication/postSearch"`.